# Include line breaks in email sent via batch file

Tags: email, batch

```
"\\File\Path\To\Program.EXE" AUTORUN="report" /SYS OUTPUT= MAPI (TO="bob@email.com.au" SUBJECT="Report" MESSAGE="Hi, Please find attached your statement. Regards, Bob." STYLE=PDF)
```

The above batch file runs a program which generates a report, then emails the report as an attachment.
This all works however when sending the email their are no line breaks in the body of the email message.

How do I add in line breaks so the message reads as below?

> Hi,
>
> Please find attached your statement.
>
> Regards, Bob

Comment: Which mail server/software?

Comment: [Insert a line break in mailto body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765834/insert-a-line-break-in-mailto-body)

Comment: In what format is the message sent, eg plain text, HTML, Rich Text?

Answer (score 3):

You give no information about the program that is actually sending the email. So I can only give you a couple of general options. One of them might do the trick:

- Put "< p >" (without the quotes) were you want a line-break.
- Try "< br >" (without the quotes)
- Try "\n" (again: without the quotes).
- Some programs allow the body of the mail to be read from a file in stead of a command-line parameter. So check the documentation if that can be used.